# how to print object value with String method

Tags: java, string, abstract-class

I have an abstract class like this

```
public abstract class Temperature
```

{

```
private float value;
public Temperature(float v)
{
    value = v;
}

public final float getValue()
{
    return value;
}

public abstract Temperature toCelsius();
public abstract Temperature toFahrenheit();
public abstract Temperature toKelvin();
}
```

then I have classes that extend this Temperature class, example:

```
 public class Celsius extends Temperature
{
public Celsius(float t)
{
    super(t);
}


public String toString()
{
    return "";
}


@Override
public Temperature toCelsius() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this;
}

public Temperature toKelvin(){
    return new Kelvin(this.getValue() + 273);
}

@Override
public Temperature toFahrenheit() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return new Fahrenheit(this.getValue() * 9 / 5 +32);
}
```

}

main method creates objects of of Celcius

```
     Temperature inputTemp = null, outputTemp = null;

     inputTemp = new Celsius(temp_val);

     outputTemp = inputTemp.toCelsius();
```

then prints the object by calling this method

```
     System.out.println("\n The converted temperature is " + outputTemp.toString() +"\n\n");
    }
```

What do i have to put in the toString method in order to print the desired value? this.super.getValue() didnt work and im kinda clueless. Since we are not going to be returning the same object everytime, dont we have to use the superclass?

Comment: Did you notice what your toString method returns ? "" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be enough if you use:

```
public String toString()
{
    return Float.toString(this.getValue());
}
```

Comment: cannot invoke toString() on the primitive type float @_@

Comment: @ApprenticeProgrammer Sorry, that's right. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

`this.super` is invalid syntax. `super` is not a field of `this`. It's a keyword that allows calling the superclass implementation of a method rather than calling the overridden implementation, from the current class. You just need

```
return Float.toString(this.getValue());
```

or

```
return Float.toString(getValue());
```

or even

```
return Float.toString(super.getValue());
```

But using `super.getValue()` is useless, since the subclass doesn't override the base `getValue()` method, and you thus don't need to explicitely use the super implementation of the method.